# Echoing the microphone input

Tags: windows-xp, audio, microphone, headphones

I'm using Windows XP. I have plugged in a microphone, and I need to send the input immediately to the headphone for all the time the microphone remains active. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the volume control. From the menu, chose "Select devices for playback" (or something similar, I'm not near Win XP right now). Check the microphone check box. From now on, the controls for your microphone should show up on the volume controls. Uncheck "Mute".

This works only if your sound card supports it (which should, but all sound cards are different, so I don't know).

Comment: What you describe is the procedure to activate the microphone. I have already done it. But I need to send the microphone input to the output device (headphone or other one).

Comment: There are two kind of controls in volume controls. One for recording, and one for playback. For the recording, you select what you want to be recorded. For the playback, you select what you want to send to the output. By default, the microphone is not shown on the playback controls, because most people use it only for recording. If you activate it there, it should send the input to your headphone.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Evidently all the pc I use do not have such option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch monitoring on. [Here](http://www.winvistatips.com/realtek-microphone-monitor-heres-t12128.html) is a link.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.